# How to write automation script to Identify node index of list, with link text ‘Setup First Project’ using xpath

Tags: selenium

I am trying to write automation script to Identify node index of list, with link text ‘Setup First Project’ using xpath and Get the text associated with link node next to above.

[image]

Comment: You want text or href?

Comment: First of all Thanks for the responses, My ask is to get to identify the position (index ) of link for link text  ‘Setup First Project’.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Locate element use below line.

WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()="Setup First Project"]"));

To get text from element use getText() method.

String text= link.getText();

Answer (score 0):

Use the below xpath:-
//a[text()="Setup First Project"]

Answer (score 0):

If you care for speed and you can deppend on the <section id="recent-posts-3", use this xpath:

```
//section[@id='recent-posts-3']/ul/li/a[text()="Setup First Project"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I wrote script to save all links and then print index of required link text.

//Save all links available on the page as List
        


List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a"));
        int setupIndex=0;
        for(int i =0;i<links.size();i++) {
            String elementText = links.get(i).getText();
            if(elementText.equals("Setup First Project"))
            {
                setupIndex =i;
            }

            System.out.println(elementText);
        }

        // 5.2 Identify node index of list, with link text ‘Setup First Project’

        System.out.println("the index is"+ setupIndex);

        //5.3 Get the text associated with link node next to ‘Setup First Project’
        System.out.println(links.get(setupIndex+1).getText());
    }
```